# Multiplying only the lines with numeric value in linux/awk/bash

Tags: linux, shell, awk

I want to multiply each numeric line with numeric value (e.g., 2), except the line has header (character line with spaces).

Input.file

```
fixedStep chrom=chr1 start=9992 step=1
3
6
10
23
...
fixedStep chrom=chr1 start=11166 step=1
2
4
6
 ...
```

Expected Output

```
fixedStep chrom=chr1 start=9992 step=1
6
12
20
46
...
fixedStep chrom=chr1 start=11166 step=1
4
8
12
...
```

My code:

```
while read line; do echo 2*$line;  done <Input.file | bc
```

This code does the multiplication perfectly but does not keep the header as it was. Can anyone help?

Sample output of my code:

```
(standard_in) 1: illegal character: S
(standard_in) 1: parse error
(standard_in) 1: parse error
(standard_in) 1: parse error
6
12
20
46
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use awk:

```
awk 'NF==1{$1 *= 2} 1' file
fixedStep chrom=chr1 start=9992 step=1
6
12
20
46
0
fixedStep chrom=chr1 start=11166 step=1
4
8
12
```

Or to check if first field is numeric:

```
awk '$1*1{$1 *= 2} 1' file
```

Answer (score 1):

Perl solution:

```
perl -lpe '$_ *= 2 if /^[0-9]+$/' Input.file
```

- `-l` handles newlines.
- `-p` reads the input line by line and prints it.
- `$_` is the topic variable. If it contains only digits, it's multiplied by 2.

Answer (score 1):

When I try to stay close to the OP's solution, use bc only for fields with a space.

```
while read line; do
        if [[ "${line}" = *\ * ]]; then
           echo $line
        else
           echo 2*$line | bc
        fi
done <Input.file
```

You can improve this by replacing `bc` with `((line *= 2))` and showing the result. When you use this method you can skip the if-statement:

```
while read line; do
   (( line *= 2 )) 2>/dev/null
   echo $line
done <Input.file
```